# Django URL Slugs

Tags: django, models

I have a comment and a post model.

I want the URL to come out as /post//comment//

But I am unsure how to set this up.

My Post model has this:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return 'appname:post', (self.slug,)
```

can my comment model have:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Comment(models.Model):
    ...
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return 'appname:post:comment', (self.slug,)
```

or how do I hook up get_absolute_url so that the url comes out the way I mentioned? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Comment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='authors')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='comments', null=True, blank=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='comments', null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title    

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        if self.project:
            return ('comment', (), {
                'project': self.task.id,
                'slug': self.slug,
                'id': self.id,
            })            
        elif self.task:
            return ('comment', (), {
                'project': self.task.project.id,
                'task': self.task.id,
                'slug': self.slug,
                'id': self.id,
            })
```

and then hook up the urls.py to use all the necessary id's for the url named 'comment'